# SNMP commands not working from the device itself. Works fine from different location

Tags: snmp, net-snmp, mib, oid

I am having trouble setting and even getting SNMP values from my devices itself, but I can from a remote location.

Here is my snmpd.conf file. As you can see, *for this test only*, I have two communities that I granted full access to. (I will change my public community to read only after, don't worry)

```
com2sec rw default public
com2sec rw localhost private
group public v1 rw
group public v2c rw
group public usm rw
group private v1 rw
group private v2c rw
group private usm rw
view all included .1
access public "" any noauth exact all all all
access private "" any noauth exact all all all
```

Here I can set and get my SNMP values from a remote location.

```
$ snmpget -v2c -c public x.x.x.x SNMPv2-MIB::sysName.0
SNMPv2-MIB::sysName.0 = STRING: default
$ snmpset -v2c -c public x.x.x.x SNMPv2-MIB::sysName.0 s "TEST_TEST"
SNMPv2-MIB::sysName.0 = STRING: TEST_TEST
$ snmpget -v2c -c public x.x.x.x SNMPv2-MIB::sysName.0
SNMPv2-MIB::sysName.0 = STRING: TEST_TEST
$
```

Now when I try it from the device itself...this is what I get. I cannot snmpwalk it or anything. Why?

```
$ snmpget -v2c -c private localhost SNMPv2-MIB::sysName.0
Cannot find module (SNMP-VIEW-BASED-ACM-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (SNMP-COMMUNITY-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (SNMP-FRAMEWORK-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (SNMP-MPD-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (SNMP-USER-BASED-SM-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (TUNNEL-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (IPV6-FLOW-LABEL-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (UCD-DLMOD-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (IP-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (IF-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (TCP-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (UDP-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (HOST-RESOURCES-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (SNMPv2-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (SNMPv2-SMI): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (NOTIFICATION-LOG-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (DISMAN-EVENT-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (DISMAN-SCHEDULE-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
getaddrinfo: localhost Name or service not known
snmpget: Unknown host (localhost) (No such file or directory)
```

I want to be able to change some values from my device so I can snmpwalk it and get the values. All help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Clearly `localhost` cannot be resolved correctly,

`getaddrinfo: localhost Name or service not known`

Did you try `127.0.0.1` for IP v4, or `::1` for IP v6?

Comment: I did. I still get all the "Cannot find module" and `SNMPv2-MIB::sysName.0: Unknown Object Identifier` after it. I tried all these.

Comment: @user2537383, does the line `getaddrinfo: localhost Name or service not known` disappear when you use IP addresses? If so, then you can check whether you have proper net-snmp installation which contains the default MIB documents, http://net-snmp.sourceforge.net/tutorial/tutorial-5/commands/mib-options.html Without such documents, `snmpget` cannot understand what is `SNMPv2-MIB::sysName.0`

Answer (score 0):

The machine running your snmpwalk / snmpget command appears not have all the MIBs it needs. Or maybe doesn't know where they are.

Anyway I was getting similar errors on an Ubuntu 12 machine, in a docker container. Fixed with "apt-get install snmp-mibs-downloader" but that package is only available if you add this to /etc/apt/sources.list (don't forget "apt-get update"):

```
## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise multiverse" >>  /etc/apt/sources.list
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise multiverse" >>  /etc/apt/sources.list
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates multiverse" >>  /etc/apt/sources.list
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates multiverse" >>  /etc/apt/sources.list
```